# Prove that $\int_{B^n} 1 dx=|B^n|$

Tags: integration

Let $B^n=\left\{x\in \mathbb R^n: ||x||\le1 \right\}$. Prove that $\int_{B^n} 1 dx=|B^n|$

This is a fact that I use to solve my tasks, but I do not quite understand why this is true

Comment: The one-dimensional version is $\int_a^b 1 \ dx = b-a$.

Comment: Riemann or Lebesgue integration?

Comment: What kind of integration are you doing? In the Lebesgue theory, this holds by definition.

Comment: @Thorgott Lebesgue theory

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for a measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\int_A dm=m(A).
$$
In your case, $m(B^n)$ is the volume of $B^n$.